# implement linear probing in c++ for a generic type

Tags: c++, templates, hashtable, linear-probing

I wanted to implement linear probing for hashtabe in c++,but the key,value
pair would be of generic type like: **vector< pair< key,value> >**(where key,value is of generic type).

Now,in linear probing if a cell is occupied we traverse the vector until we find an empty cell and then place the new pair in that cell.

The problem is,that in generic type,how would I be able to check if a particular cell is occupied or not?
I cannot use these conditions:

```
if(key == '\0')//As key is not of type string
```

**OR**

```
if(key == 0)//As key is not of type int
```

So,how will be able to check if a paricular cell in the vector is empty or not?
Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept.

Comment: You may specialize the function containing that code.

Comment: You might need another data-structure that has knowledge of itself being "empty" or not.

Comment: But how can I specialize the function?

Comment: Associate an extra flag to the cells, preferably as a packed array of bits.

Comment: You can't. There are some things C++ does not allow you do. You can of course build a parallel array of flags, but that isn't really answering the question. You can only require your templated type to support an "isnull" method of some description, and then the code is not generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just check if the element of the vector has meaningful key and value:

```
if(vector[i] == std::pair<key, value>())
    //empty
```

or, if you only care about the keys

```
if(vector[i].first == key())
    //empty
```

This approach assumes that the default constructor of `key` type constructs an object that would be considered an "empty" or "invalid" key.

Comment: What happens if `key` or `value` doesn't have a default value? An `int` for example?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR, why wouldn't they? An int would be initialized with 0 in this case. Of course this approach assumes that the default constructor of `key` type creates an object which is considered an `empty` or `invalid` key. Edited the answer to emphasize that.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall,should I make an empty pair(in the constructor) for each index of the vector?Wouldn't this put a constraint that the size of the vector should be known beforehand.

Comment: @Saurabh, not necessarily. You just need to make sure that when an element in a vector is removed, you either 1) really delete it from the vector, or 2) replace is with an empty pair. This way when you traverse the vector later, you will either find an empty pair somewhere and use that cell, _or_ reach the end of the vector, and append to it.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall,just one thing more.I wrote some code accordingly,please see the link: (https://gist.github.com/Sharma96/f312af6b3219c992dd1519a572dfddf3)         .There is a weird thing happening in the code,if you will run the code,you will find that when the value of y(in ch function) is 5,it is printing 135057 for the value v[y].first,how is it initializing the value for the pair at the 5th index(and only the 5th index),while I am calling the add function 4 times only.

Comment: @Saurabh, you are accessing out-of-bounds index (your vector only has 4 items, and in `ch()` you are accessing more), this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for checking the code.But,then how come it is printing some arbitrary value only for the 5th index and 0 for 6,7,8,9 indexes?

Comment: @Saurabh you are accessing memory that doesn't belong to you. You can get anything there. It can be 0, it can be trash, it can be some meaningful data, or your may just get a set fault and crash.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free function `isEmpty` for checking if a key type is empty. Define a templated default function that works for most types, and make special functions that cannot be handled by the default.

E.g.

```
template<typename T>
bool isEmpty(const T &t) {
    return !t;
}

bool isEmpty(const std::string &s) {
   return s.length() == 0;
}

bool isEmpty(double d) {
    return d < 0;
}

isEmpty(0); // true
isEmpty(1); // false
isEmpty(std::string()); // true
isEmpty(std::string("not empty")); // false
isEmpty(1.0); // false
isEmpty(-1.0); // true
```

You only need to specialize for key types that do not have an `operator !` or where a different logic is needed for the check

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to rule out the possibility to have "default constructed" elements in your hash you can build a parallel data structure, like a `std::bitset` (if you know in advance the maximum size of your data structure) or a `std::vector<bool>`, that in the following i will call `has`. `has[i]` will be true if `vector[i]` contains a valid, actually inserted element.

So the operations should be modified as follows:

- **insert**: go on scanning the vector until you find a position `i` such that `has[i] == false`
- **remove element in position i**: set `has[i]` to `false`

Hope this helps